# Problem connecting to angular app in docker

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I want to run an angular app in a docker container, in development mode with the possibility that when I make changes they are auto-generated on the local web. I've tried various configurations and I can't connect to port 4200.

Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:14.17.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

# Instalamos angular cli en nuestra imágen
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli && npm cache clean

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Compose file:

```
 frontend:
build: ./frontend
ports:
  - "4200:4200"
container_name: frontend
volumes:
  - "./frontend:/app"
  - "/app/node_modules"
  - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
environment:
  - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

When I run the docker container it starts fine. But when I try to access from the browser to localhost:4200, I get the error "This site cannot be reached"

Comment: Please show your `docker run` command. Do you have a [port mapping](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) like this `-p 4200:4200` defined in your run command?

Comment: I believe the EXPOSE port syntax is: `EXPOSE 4200:4200` to bind 4200 on the host

Comment: I map the port in the compose file

Comment: Try using de docker container ip: docker_ip:4200 to know the ip you can execute that: sudo docker container inspect container_name_or_ID

Comment: @BrandonTaylor No. You can't bind a port from the EXPOSE statement.

Comment: @HansKilian I beg to differ. We do this in all of our Dockerfiles

Comment: @BrandonTaylor OK. I'll show you my reference. Then you show me yours? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: @HansKilian Here's what I was referencing: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

Comment: @BrandonTaylor As I read that, that's the `docker run` command reference. Not the Dockerfile reference.

Comment: I think the syntax applies to Dockerfiles as well. We haven't had any issues exposing ports this way

Answer (score 3):

Your Angular app is probably *bound* to localhost by default, meaning that it'll only accept connections from inside the container.

In your package.json file, the `start` script is probably defined as `ng serve`. It needs to be `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`. That will allow the app to accept connections from outside the container.

If the start script isn't `ng serve`, then please edit your post and add the contents of your package.json file to it.